# Fit a long algorithm into a beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, formatting, algorithms

I want to include the following algorithm in beamer frame. My MWE is shown below

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\mode<presentation>

\usetheme{Madrid}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{algpseudocode,algorithm,algorithmicx}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]

\usepackage{xkeyval}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{} % Allow optional arguments after frame.

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue}

\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry title}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry location}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry note}{}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\centerline{\textbf{INTRODUCTION}}}
%\framesubtitle{\centerline{frame subtitle}}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{Pseudocode for the GWO}
    \label{gwo}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        %   \Procedure{Hybrid BAT-Genetic Algorithm}{}
        \\Input :Grey wolf population:$X_{i}(i = 1, 2, ..., n)$,Maximum Number of iteration:Max\_it
        \\Output :$X_{a}$ : Optimal Position(Optimized filter coefficients)
        \\Objective function : PSNR
        \hrule
        \\Initialize the Grey wolf population $X_{i} = (i=1,2, ...,n)$
        \\Initialize the coefficient vectors a, A, and C
        \State $\vec{A}=2\vec{a}\vec{r_1}-\vec{a}$
        \State $\vec{C}=2\vec{r_2}$
        \Comment where components of are linearly decreased from 2 to 0 over the course of iterations and,\\ are random vectors in $[0,1]$
        \For{all $X_{i}$}
        \State Calculate fitness $F(X_{i})$ of all $X_{i}$
        \EndFor
        \State Rank the gray wolf in descending order based on the fitness
        \State $X_{\alpha}$ = the first search agent
        \State $X_{\beta}$ = the second search agent
        \State $X_{\delta}$ = the third search agent 
        \State t=1;
        \While{t\textless Max\_it}
        \For{i=1:n}
        \State Update the position of the current search agent $\vec{F}(t+1) = \frac{\vec{F_{1}}+\vec{F_{2}}+\vec{F_{3}}}{3}$
        \EndFor
        \State Update $a$,$A$, and $C$
        \For{all $X_{i}$}
        \State Calculate fitness $F(X_{i})$ of all $X_{i}$
        \EndFor
        \State Update $X_{\alpha}$, $X_{\beta}$, and $X_{\delta}$
        \State t=t+1;
        \EndWhile
        \State Return the first best agent $X_{\alpha}$ found so far
        \\Post-processing the results and visualization
        %   \EndProcedure
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess the problem is that the agorithm does not fit on a beamer slide. The idea with beamer is to make presenteations, and as such I normally view everything that does not fit in a frame as too detailed. I think there is a risk that you will lose some of the attention from the audience with a slide like this. My advice would be to describe the algorithm in (much) less details. Then it will both fit the slide and people will have chance to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I broke your algorithm into two frames...

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\mode<presentation>

\usetheme{Madrid}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{algpseudocode,algorithm,algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algcompatible}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{xkeyval}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{} % Allow optional arguments after frame.

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue}

\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry title}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry location}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry note}{}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\centerline{\textbf{INTRODUCTION}}}
%\framesubtitle{\centerline{frame subtitle}}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{Pseudocode for the GWO}
    \label{gwo}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        %   \Procedure{Hybrid BAT-Genetic Algorithm}{}
        \\Input :Grey wolf population:$X_{i}(i = 1, 2, ..., n)$,Maximum Number of iteration:Max\_it
        \\Output :$X_{a}$ : Optimal Position(Optimized filter coefficients)
        \\Objective function : PSNR
        \hrule
        \\Initialize the Grey wolf population $X_{i} = (i=1,2, ...,n)$
        \\Initialize the coefficient vectors a, A, and C
        \State $\vec{A}=2\vec{a}\vec{r_1}-\vec{a}$
        \State $\vec{C}=2\vec{r_2}$
        \Comment where components of are linearly decreased from 2 to 0 over the course of iterations and,\\ are random vectors in $[0,1]$
        \For{all $X_{i}$}
        \State Calculate fitness $F(X_{i})$ of all $X_{i}$
        \EndFor
\algstore{myalg}
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\centerline{\textbf{INTRODUCTION}}}


      \begin{algorithm}[H]
     \ContinuedFloat
%     \caption{Pseudocode for the GWO}
     \begin{algorithmic}[1]
     \algrestore{myalg}
        \State Rank the gray wolf in descending order based on the fitness
        \State $X_{\alpha}$ = the first search agent
        \State $X_{\beta}$ = the second search agent
        \State $X_{\delta}$ = the third search agent 
        \State t=1;
        \While{t\textless Max\_it}
        \For{i=1:n}
        \State Update the position of the current search agent \mbox{$\vec{F}(t+1) = \frac{\vec{F_{1}}+\vec{F_{2}}+\vec{F_{3}}}{3}$}
        \EndFor
        \State Update $a$,$A$, and $C$
        \For{all $X_{i}$}
        \State Calculate fitness $F(X_{i})$ of all $X_{i}$
        \EndFor
        \State Update $X_{\alpha}$, $X_{\beta}$, and $X_{\delta}$
        \State t=t+1;
        \EndWhile
        \State Return the first best agent $X_{\alpha}$ found so far
        \\Post-processing the results and visualization
        %   \EndProcedure
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```